# How to find specific pixel in tkinter window

Tags: python, tkinter, pixel

I am working on my gui with tkinter, and I have to place stuff in precise places, i can't just use pack. Currently i write almost random numbers for `width` and `height` in `place()`, then run, adjust the numbers, repeat the program and check the position until the button or label fits just perfectly.

Isn't there a simpler way? Is there an option of the python launcher that allows me to point somewhere in the window and find out the coordinates?
Or maybe an extention for vcscode or a setting for pycharm?

Comment: first of, do You mean `x` and `y` kwargs for `.place()`? second, You could say bind a mouse button 1 event to root window or whichever window or container You need to get those coords from and then just print the `event.x` and `event.y`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is about the simplest way of getting mouse coordinates

```py
from tkinter import Tk


root = Tk()

root.bind('<Button-1>', lambda e: print(e.x, e.y))

root.mainloop()
```

basically `.bind()` binds an event (as the name suggests) to the widget and when the event is triggered `.bind()` method calls the given function while also passing an `event` argument so that has to be dealt with but it can also be used as in this case (and in most cases actually)

P.S. `e` is just a preference of mine when using `lambda` in this case and if I were to define a function as usually I would use `event` as argument name

Answer (score 0):

As @Matiiss stated in his answer, using can use mouse coordinates.

Also, there is another event called `<Motion>` which you can use.

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
lbl=Label(root,text='')
lbl.pack()
lbl1=Label(root,text='')
lbl1.pack()
root.bind("<Motion>",lambda e: [lbl.config(text=f"X pixel: {e.x}"),lbl1.config(text=f"Y pixel: {e.y}")])
root.mainloop()
```